# What is the needed permissions for a Gitlab CI/CD and Vault secret integration?

Tags: terraform, gitlab, gitlab-ci, hashicorp-vault, vault

I'm configuring a Gitlab CI pipeline and I need to retrieve a secret from my Hashicorp Vault. I did configure as the [Gitlab Docs - Hashicorp Vault KV-V2](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/secrets/convert-to-id-tokens.html#kv-secrets-engine-v2).

I have a role attached to this JWT authentication back-end on my Hashicorp Vault and I want to know what is the needed permissions that I have to write on a Vault Policy used by this role because with the actual policy, when the pipeline runs I got the error:

```
Resolving secrets
Resolving secret "VAULT_SECRET_ID"...
Using "vault" secret resolver...
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): resolving secrets: reading secret: reading from Vault: api error: status code 403: 1 error occurred:
    * permission denied
```

Here is my Vault JWT Authentication configs (configured via Terraform).

```
data "vault_policy_document" "gitlab_jwt" {
  rule {
    capabilities = ["create", "read"]
    path         = "auth/jwt/gitlab"
  }

  rule {
    capabilities = ["read"]
    path         = "auth/jwt/gitlab/role/gitlab"
  }

  rule {
    capabilities = ["read"]
    path         = "devops/example/secret"
  }
}

resource "vault_policy" "gitlab_jwt" {
  name   = "vault-gitlab-jwt"
  policy = data.vault_policy_document.gitlab_jwt.hcl
}

resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend" "gitlab" {
  description  = "Gitlab JWT authentication"
  path         = "jwt/gitlab"
  bound_issuer = "https://gitlab.com"
  jwks_url     = "https://gitlab.com/-/jwks"
}

resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend_role" "gitlab" {
  backend                 = vault_jwt_auth_backend.gitlab.path
  role_name               = "gitlab"
  role_type               = "jwt"
  token_no_default_policy = true
  token_explicit_max_ttl  = 60
  token_policies          = [vault_policy.gitlab_jwt.name]
  user_claim              = "user_login"
  bound_claims_type       = "glob"
  bound_claims = {
    project_path = "example/*"
  }
}
```

Here is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

```
variables:
  VAULT_SERVER_URL: "https://vault.example.com"
  VAULT_AUTH_PATH: "jwt/gitlab"
  VAULT_AUTH_ROLE: "gitlab"
  VAULT_FORMAT: "json"


vault:
  id_tokens:
    VAULT_ID_TOKEN:
      aud: $VAULT_SERVER_URL
  secrets:
    VAULT_ROLE_ID:
      vault: example/secret/key@devops
      file: false
    VAULT_SECRET_ID:
      vault: example/secret/key@devops
      file: false
  ...
```

I know that the problem is about the Vault Policy attached to the JWT authentication role because when I changed the policy for a root-policy and it works perfectly:

```
data "vault_policy_document" "gitlab_jwt" {
  rule {
    capabilities = ["create", "read", "update", "delete", "patch"]
    path         = "*"
  }
}
```

Based on these Vault configurations, how can I wrote a secure policy to allow the JWT Authentication coming from Gitlab without using a root-policy for the role?

Comment: I can't see any obvious problems with what you have, so I would suggest slowly tweaking that root-policy to narrow down what paths it can access until it stops working to see if that gives any clues

Answer (score 0):

I would try it this way:

```
resource "vault_policy" "gitlab_jwt" {
  name   = "vault-gitlab-jwt"
   policy = <<EOT
    path "devops/example/secret/*" {
      capabilities = ["read"]
    }
    EOT
    }
}


resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend" "gitlab" {
  description  = "Gitlab JWT authentication"
  path         = "jwt"
  bound_issuer = "https://gitlab.com"
  jwks_url     = "https://gitlab.com/-/jwks"
}


resource "vault_jwt_auth_backend_role" "gitlab" {
  backend                 = vault_jwt_auth_backend.gitlab.path
  role_name               = "gitlab"
  role_type               = "jwt"
  token_max_ttl           = 60
  token_policies          = [vault_policy.gitlab_jwt.name]
  user_claim              = "user_login"
  bound_claims_type       = "glob"
  bound_claims = {
    "namespace_path": "example/*"
  }
```

Maybe you already solved it a long time ago :) Sorry then

In the pipeline audience should be gitlab. not vault URL.

Also keep in mind if you use HCP Vault, an extra Variable is needed:

export VAULT_NAMESPACE=admin

I configured Gitlab successfully with self-hosted Vault and with the HCP as well.